# Sitecore 8.1: Switching from Lucene to SOLR - Getting no results from SearchContext

Tags: solr, sitecore, sitecore8.1

I have switched to **SOLR** search in **Sitecore 8.1** and everything is fine (indices rebuild normally). However, when I search for items using the `SearchContext` I get no results when I filter according to `item.Path.Contains("")` although it worked using **Lucene**. If I remove the `item.Path.Contains("")`, I get results. So, why doesn't it work?
This is the code used:

```
        List<NewsSearchResultItem> results = new List<NewsSearchResultItem>();
        var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_web_index");

        using (IProviderSearchContext context = index.CreateSearchContext())
        {
            var tempResults = context.GetQueryable<NewsSearchResultItem>()
                   .Where(item => item.Path.Contains("/sitecore/content/News"))
                   .Take(10);

            results = tempResults.ToList();
        }

        return results.Select(s => new NewsViewModel(s.GetItem())).ToList();
```

Comment: Try to use lowercase path?

Comment: lowercase was part of the problem. But then no results showed, I rebuilt all me indices again, then i started getting part of the results and not all, i rebuilt my indices one more time and then i got the actual results. I don't think this is normal, is it? However, you have helped a lot, thank you, you've been awesome today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr with Sitecore stores text fields as lowercase fields by default.

Change your `Where` clause to use `path/toLower()`:

```cs
var pathToLower = "/sitecore/content/news";
... .Where(item => item.Path.Contains(pathToLower))
```

Also remember to add filters to use your current language only - there might be some documents in Solr for Sitecore items despite the fact that they don't have any versions in a particular language.

Answer (score 1):

This could be as Marek said, a lower case issue, However you can also try to use `Paths` property instead of `Path`, as following:

```cs
var tempResults = context.GetQueryable<NewsSearchResultItem>()
                   .Where(item => item.Paths.Contains(Sitecore.Data.ID.Parse("News Item ID (GUID)")))
                   .Take(10);
```